# Bootstrap 'col' tag does not pull articles into as many rows as it can fit

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, row

I am attempting to work with Bootstrap for the first time and having a problem implementing the 'col' tag so that it fits as much content / rows as the viewport will allow. Below is my base markup.

I believe that I am following the correct order of using a div / section tag with the class of "container text-center", then a div / class="row" tag and then an article with a class of "col". It was my understanding that if the "col" tag is not / does not have set column widths, it will then attemp to creat a row of six columns or fit as many columns as it can depending on the how the characters of the words within the columns will allow for the content to break / display / render.

I believe that what I have done ought to work. I am working with Bootstrap v4 beta 0.6 in accordance with the lynda videos as seen in [enter link description here](https://www.lynda.com/Bootstrap-tutorials/Layout-overview/372545/600593-4.html?autoplay=true)

I am hoping someone can explain / point out where I am goofing things up. I have checked Stack Overflow for a similar issue, and while I found similar issues, they all speak to the col-size-# rather then just the 'row' class itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
    img {
        width: 100px;
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<header class="clearfix" style="height: 50vh; background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover; margin-bottom: 20px;">


        <!-- container and or container-fluid -->
        <div class="container-fluid"><img src="images/wisdompetlogo.svg" alt="Wisdom Pet Logo"></div>
</header>

<section class="container text-center" id="services">
    <row>
        <article class="col">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="images/icon-exoticpets.svg" alt="Icon">
            <h3>Exotic Pets</h3>
            <p>We offer specialized care for reptiles, rodents, birds, and other exotic pets.</p>
        </article>

        <article class="col">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="images/icon-grooming.svg" alt="Icon">
            <h3>Grooming</h3>
            <p>Our therapeutic grooming treatments help battle fleas, allergic dermatitis, and other challenging skin conditions.</p>
        </article>

        <article class="col">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="images/icon-health.svg" alt="Icon">
            <h3>General Health</h3>
            <p>Wellness and senior exams, ultrasound, x-ray, and dental cleanings are just a few of our general health services.</p>
        </article>

        <article class="col">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="images/icon-nutrition.svg" alt="Icon">
            <h3>Nutrition</h3>
            <p>Let our nutrition experts review your pet's diet and prescribe a custom nutrition plan for optimum health and disease prevention.</p>
        </article>

        <article class="col">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="images/icon-pestcontrol.svg" alt="Icon">
            <h3>Pest Control</h3>
            <p>We offer the latest advances in safe and effective prevention and treatment of fleas, ticks, worms, heart worm, and other parasites.</p>
        </article>

        <article class="col">
            <img class="mx-auto" src="images/icon-vaccinations.svg" alt="Icon">
            <h3>Vaccinations</h3>
            <p>Our veterinarians are experienced in modern vaccination protocols that prevent many of the deadliest diseases in pets.</p>
        </article>
    </row>
</section>

</div><!-- content container -->

<script src="js/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i believe that the `<row>` should be `<div class="row">` It seems to work for me [here](http://www.bootply.com/eEQveCXep5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few minor corrections needed to make sure you achieve the results you want.

1. Change the `<row>` element to a `<div class="row">`
2. Make sure that you are loading the correct version of bootstrap

you can see it here on this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/eEQveCXep5)

Answer (score 0):

The width of bootstrap is 12 (it's using a grid). So if you want 6 articles you have to do this :

```
<article class="col-lg-2">
```

(With 6 articles, you have 12)

You can learn more here : 
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/